# Calculating the integral

Tags: calculus

I need to calculate the following integral:

$\int \frac{dx}{\sin^3x}$

I noticed that $\int \frac{dx}{\sin^3x}=\int \frac{dx}{\sin x \sin^2x}=-\int \frac{dx}{-\sin x (1-\cos^2x)}  (A)$

Let $v=\cos u \Leftrightarrow dv=-\sin u du$

Therefore: $(A)= -\int \frac{dv}{(1-v^2)^2} $ Is that correct ?

How do I calculate then the final integral.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your use of $\iff$ is incorrect. If $dv = -\sin u \ du$ it does not necessarily follow that $v = \cos u$. For example, if $v = \cos u + 1$ then $dv = -\sin u \, du.$ The correct statement is that $v = \cos u \implies dv = -\sin u \, du$. Remember that $A \iff B$ means that *both* $A \implies B$ *and* $B \implies A$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your simplification is correct.

Once you have your integrand in the form $\dfrac1{(1-v^2)^2}$. make use of partial fractions to rewrite the integrand as
$$\dfrac1{(1-v^2)^2}= \dfrac14 \left( \dfrac1{1+v} + \dfrac1{(1+v)^2} + \dfrac1{1-v} + \dfrac1{(1-v)^2}\right)$$
Now you should be able to integrate it out easily.

Answer (score 0):

In the first integral you can substitute u=cos x, this will reduce the problem to the problem of finding the integral $1/(1-u^2)^2$

Comment: ok. But I having difficulty calculating the final integral. Can you help me please?

Comment: Use partial fractions to evaluate the last integral